# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspException in JBOSS EAP 6.2 but deployed correctly in jboss-5.0.1.GA

Tags: servlets, jboss6.x

My LDAP.war is not deployed correctly in JBOSS EAP 6.2, but it is working fine in jboss-5.0.1.GA.
This class file is present in any other jar, Or its structure is changed? **org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspException**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class (`org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspException`) is present in  jasper-runtime-.jar. Adding this jar to your jboss 6 lib should resolve the issue.